# sorting class content according to few parameters

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparison

I need implement sorting for content of file.

Every line of File contain next data: `Instructor, Course, Group, Student, Result`
And can contain few results for the same student.

***for example:***

```
Paul Schwartz,Introduction to Computer Architecture,I1,Ben Dunkin,88
Muhamed Olji,Object Oriented Programming,I4,Mike Brown,73
...
Paul Schwartz,Introduction to Computer Architecture,I1,Ben Dunkin,96
```

I need to implement for every instructor

- course that is leaded by him;
- all groups that listened this course (ascending order);
- for every group `Student - Result` (descending order);
- and top 5 `Student` with higher result from this course.

I made reading from file and created class `Item`:

```
class Item { 
    private String instructor;
    private String course;
    private String group;
    private String student;
    private int result;
    // and add appropriate public getters/setters
}
```

In java, we can sort all the elements of this class using one of the two options: class implementing `Comparable` interface and overriding the `compareTo() method` or using external `Comparator` interface with `compare() method`. But how can we sort different querys of sorting using these options.

- how to use `compareTo()` to satisfy this requirements (or better `compare()`)?

Comment: Are you sorting or extracting?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I extracted and don't know how to so sorting.

Comment: You can't do one sort that will give you all the results you want (4 bullet points). They each need different information.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis Have can we achieve this aim? Any suggestions.

Comment: As @SotiriosDelimanolis has said, the solution will likely be asking for four different sorts. As such, making your class implement the `Comparable` interface or overriding the `compareTo` method will only allow you to do one type of sort. Instead opt for using an external `Comparator`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A comparator for `Item` would use the following comparison:

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator {
  public int compare(Object aObjectOne, Object aObjectTwo) {
    Item objectOne = (Item) aObjectOne;
    Item objectTwo = (Item) aObjectTwo;

    int cmpinstr = objectOne.getInstructor().compareTo(objectTwo.getInstructor());
    if (cmpinstr != 0) // different instructor
        return cmpinstr;

    int cmpcourse = objectOne.getCourse().compareTo(objectTwo.getCourse());
    if (cmpcourse != 0) // different course
        return cmpcourse;

    int cmpgroup = objectOne.getGroup().compareTo(objectTwo.getGroup());
    if (cmpgroup != 0) // different group
        return cmpgroup;

    // sorting by result.
    if (objectOne.getResult() < objectTwo.getResult())
        return -1; // i1 has lower result than i2
    else if (objectOne.getResult() > objectTwo.getResult())
        return 1; // i1 has higher result than i2

    return 0; // i1 and i2 have the same result
  }
}
```

To get the top five, simply sort and select the five last students from your collection.

If you want to filter data based on group, instructor, course or result, you can loop through the collection with some custom filter.

Comment: does this mean that we need to implement both interfaces and make `compareTo()` for group, instructor and course...

Comment: Not if you use `Collections.sort(YourObejctList, new CustomComparator());`, as Recall suggests.

Comment: you forgot casting public int compare(Object aObjectOne, Object aObjectTwo) {
        `Item objectOne = (Item) aObjectOne;`
        `Item objectTwo = (Item) aObjectTwo;`

Comment: it means that enough to made this class and class `Item` doesn't need to implement `Comparable` and override any `compareTo()`?

Comment: Only this class must implement Comparator

Comment: but what about sorting for top 10 for all course? It seems to me that need to implement `compareTo()` for `Item` and sort by results?

Comment: Basically, you need to sort and filter. You can easily filter the results by looping through all items and saving those that pass certain criteria.  After that you can sort that list to get a top-10

Answer (score 2):

You should let you class implements [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), it has a `compareTo` method just like `String` does.

So your custom comparator could look like this:

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<Item> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Item i1, Item i2) {
        return i1.compareTo(i2);
    }
}
```

(The `compare()` method must return an `int`, so you couldn't directly return a `boolean`.)

Than you need to `overwrite` the `CompareTo` Method in your `Item` class, where you define what properties should be compared.

Because you want to sort on different options you need mutliple compare methods, and multiple comparators. Than you just need to call them how you need.

Your sorting code would be just about like this:

```
Collections.sort(YourObejctList, new CustomComparator());
```

Comment: I misunderstand we make this class and need to implement `compareTo()` and compare instructors, groups and students. It's all?

Comment: yes then you just need to call the needed comparator and it will sort as u defined it